# Can any one help in what this batch file does?

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file which Copies my files from one place to another. But there are few more line of code in it which I dont understand.

```
@echo off
call D:\SystemControl\setDataDate.bat
set storeData=D:\Data_%filedate%
echo Backup Side-by-Side Systems
set copyap=robocopy
set copyparm=/S /XX /NJH /NJS /NP /NDL
set copysys=systems\main
echo %storeData%
echo --------------------------------------------------------------------   -----------------------------------------
echo.
echo System details used for gathering files
echo,
for /F "tokens=1,2*" %%A in (D:\SystemControl\systems.lst) do IF %%A NEQ     void echo %%A %%B %%C
echo.
echo --------------------------------------------------------------------   -----------------------------------------
set runmstar=call d:\mstar\mstarhome\bus\bin\mstarrun.bat
IF NOT EXIST %storeData%\logs for /F "tokens=1,2*" %%A in     (D:\SystemControl\systems.lst) do IF %%A NEQ void md %storeData%\logs
for /F "tokens=1,2*" %%A in (D:\SystemControl\systems.lst) do IF %%A NEQ     void del %%Csystems\main\_MARKED_FOR_DELETION_*.* /S
for /F "tokens=1,2*" %%A in (D:\SystemControl\systems.lst) do echo     %%C%copysys%systems\logs to %storeData%\logs


pause
for /F "tokens=1,2*" %%A in (D:\SystemControl\systems.lst) do IF %%A NEQ     void del %storeData%\%%B\logs\*_service_*.log /Q
for /F "tokens=1,2*" %%A in (D:\SystemControl\systems.lst) do IF %%A NEQ void del %storeData%\%%B\logs\iAssignment\iAssignmen*.log /Q
for /F "tokens=1,2*" %%A in (D:\SystemControl\systems.lst) do IF %%A NEQ void del %storeData%\%%B\logs\Cycle*.log /Q
for /F "tokens=1,2*" %%A in (D:\SystemControl\systems.lst) do IF %%A NEQ void del %storeData%\%%B\logs\Comms*.log /Q
pause
for /F "tokens=1,2*" %%A in (D:\SystemControl\systems.lst) do IF %%A NEQ void md %storeData%\%%B\perfmon
for /F "tokens=1,2*" %%A in (D:\SystemControl\systems.lst) do IF %%A NEQ void %copyap% %%Cperfmon %storeData%\%%B\perfmon\ *.csv %copyparm%
for /F "tokens=1,2*" %%A in (D:\SystemControl\systems.lst) do IF %%A NEQ void rd %%Cperfmon /s /Q

pause
```

Like: why pause have been used,
the copy parameter is used to copy the files, but why copyap, copysys and copy* words are used.
why del is used . 
Why is %storeData% used ?

Comment: it seems to be processing some type of data from the system

Comment: if you are just trying to move files you can/should use the Move command

Comment: Go to [Command-line reference A-Z](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754340.aspx) and read about the commands used here like __set, copy, pause, for, if, del__ or open a command prompt window and enter `set /?`, `copy /?`, ... to get the help of those commands output directly on your screen for reading. `copyab` is an environment variable with a stupid name with string `robocopy` assigned which is a tool to copy files. And %copyab% references on execution the string `robocopy` of environment variable `copyab`.